# Multiple Event Dispatch Threads

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I am new to Java Swing and my question is related to Event Queues and Dispatch threads.

I read that it is possible to have multiple event queues , each per [AppContext](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/awt/sun/awt/AppContext.java.java-doc.htm) instance. Similarly does it mean each AppContext Event queue has its own event dispatch thread.

Comment: Is there a reason you would want multiple EDTs or is this theoretical?

Comment: @Gnon My intention was to know how does if only one dispatch thread exists handle multiple event queues.

Comment: If you could provide a link to where you read this that would help. :)

Comment: @Gnon http://www.javafaq.nu/java-bookpage-13-5.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible to have one event dispatch thread as far as I'm aware.

Apparently [AppContext is not meant to be used by developers](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-bookpage-13-5.html), although I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: I came to know that each AppContext usually assigned for a separate thread group has its own queue, which indirectly says it has its own EDT

Comment: I guess having two AppContexts running on the same JVM would give you two EDTs, although they are for most purposes completely separate programs.

Answer (score 1):

1) basically you only needed to know if your code will be done on EDT (all changes must be done on EDT),

2) if you have any doubts, it is possible to test

```
if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
```

or (that's same and returns true if is on EDT)

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
```

more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205537/edt-location-with-several-jframe-window) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater/7197098#7197098)

3) all output from Background tasks must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, basic stuff about [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)